# Web Scraping with Python BeautifulSoup 4

Tags: python, html, database, beautifulsoup

I am fairly new to Webscraping and gave my attempt after watching some tutorial videos online. I decided to use `Tripadvisor.com` and try to gather data from customer reviews.

**This is what I came up with (code):**

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/Attraction_Review-g293916-d12033454-
Reviews-SHOW_DC-Bangkok.html'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"ui_column is-9"})

for container in containers:
   rating = container.div.div.div.span["class"]

    comment_container = container.p
    comment = comment_container[0]

    print("rating" + rating)
    print("comment" + comment)
```

**This was the output of my code:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trip_advisor.py", line 18, in <module>
    comment = comment_container[0]
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1011, in 
__getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 0
```

Can anyone help me fix this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to access the contents by using the index in a `<class bs4.element.Tag'>`, you need `.contents` for that:

```
>>> container.p
<p class="partial_entry">I was there couple of weeks ago on the weekend. There was an event but it was not very crowded thought and I actually like it. What drawn my attention is the PUB on the roof top. A Pub in a department store sound pretty...<span class="taLnk ulBlueLinks" onclick="ta.prwidgets.call('handlers.clickExpand',event,this);">More</span></p>
>>> container.p.contents[0]
'I was there couple of weeks ago on the weekend. There was an event but it was not very crowded thought and I actually like it. What drawn my attention is the PUB on the roof top. A Pub in a department store sound pretty...'
```

Besides this issue, I'm not sure if your `rating` scraping is really getting what you want, but this solves the main error:

```
for container in containers:
    rating = container.div.div.div.span["class"]
    comment_container = container.p.contents
    comment = comment_container[0]
    print("Rating: ", rating)
    print("Comment: " + comment)
```

This prints:

```
Rating:  ['ui_bubble_rating', 'bubble_40']
Comment: I was there couple of weeks ago on the weekend. There was an event but it was not very crowded thought and I actually like it. What drawn my attention is the PUB on the roof top. A Pub in a department store sound pretty...
Rating:  ['ui_bubble_rating', 'bubble_50']
Comment: Show dc is very fascinating place that you must to go. The mega complex is very special from the others mall in thailand. I think you can touching and feeling of the hapiness. I went there few days ago for find some dining and spending...
```